# JDBC Phoenix driver for HBASE, retries 36 and throws exception

Tags: java, jdbc, hbase, apache-phoenix, phoenix-channels

I have a standalone HBase installed in a server(Remote).
I written a Java Client, which communicates using Phoenix, and saw it tries for 36 attempts and hence throws exception.

```
HBase-Version : 1.1.5
Phoenix-core: 4.8.0-HBase-1.1
```

ConnectionString:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:192.168.1.xxx:2181");
```

Am I missing somethinghere, cz its not connecting at all.

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=36, exceptions:
Mon Oct 17 11:50:18 IST 2016, null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=80992: row 'SYSTEM:CATALOG,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=HOSTNAME,16201,1476683863488, seqNum=0
```

Can some one help me out..!

Comment: Please take a look at [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nosql-databases/yr9GKevhezs), might help... Could be a region server issue!

Comment: Does it by default access the HadoopSystems?, any Idea about that?

Comment: I'm not sure about that @peaceUser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well its internal ip mapping error, 

 **Anybody, struggles first push of the request towards server,** please makesure the host string is configured. [Modifying host here](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/)

Comment: peaceUser - can you post the steps here? the link is not accessible now!

Comment: @mbaxi, its a working link, https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/

Comment: How was it an internap ip mapping error? Did you have the wrong ip to one of your slaves? I have the exact same problem you were having and I have tried numerous things: `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=80201`

Comment: @Zeliax, its the firewall I hope, which is not able to identify the ip address as expected.

Comment: Anybody visiting this question, I would say to check both the answers, as both remains cause for the same reason.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, this usually occurs when you're getting timeouts on the scanners. And in your case, that appears to be true, as well b/c in your error message it says:

> callTimeout=60000, callDuration=80992

meaning you went on for 81 seconds when your timeout was a minute. When querying HBase, you want to make sure you're using the rowkey or in newer versions of phoenix, the timestamp as well. Any other HBase query is going to be ridiculously inefficient. You can try a few things:

1. Try setting your HBase timeout to a ridiculously high number like 4 hours
2. Again, change your query to use the existing rowkey. In one table we have, the first character of the rowkey is 0-9 so we'll run the following:

   ```
   select * from TABLE WHERE ROWKEY like '0%' AND [other_conditions]
   select * from TABLE WHERE ROWKEY like '1%' AND [other_conditions]
   etc...
   ```

   And then combine the results or if we're counting, just multiply by 10 b/c that's usually good enough for our purposes
3. Finally, you may have to write a better rowkey to optimize for your phoenix queries. This is more of an advanced topic, but it's true of all HBase querying. HBase is good at one thing and that's querying its one, powerful index: the rowkey. Using phoenix doesn't alleviate that issue.

And by the way, from a stack overflow standpoint, it helps if you post a little about your query and your table structure.

Comment: @WattslnABox thank you for providing such detail.. and yes there is a reason behind this. It was weird that my system firewall doesn't allow the complete request to reach out the quorum...!

Comment: Ah, interesting, @peaceUser, I've never run into something like that before. I'm glad you figured it out. You can answer your own question and accept the answer

Comment: Anybody visiting this question, I would say to check both the answers, as both remains cause for the same reason.